# CakePHP: Can't update database

Tags: cakephp, syntax

I am following some online examples regarding resetting a forgotten password using CakePHP.  Here is the code:

```
    $temp = $this->User->findByEmail($this->data['User']['email']);
        $user = $temp['User']['UID'];
        $this->set('email', $this->data['User']['email']);
        if($user)
        {
            $new_salt = UsersController::generateStr();
            $new_password = UsersController::generateStr(5);
            $temp_password = Security::hash((Security::hash($new_password,'md5',false) . $new_salt), 'md5', false);
            $data = array('User' => array('UID' => $user, 'Password' => $temp_password));
            $this->User->save($data, false, array('Password'));
            $data = array('User' => array('UID' => $user, 'Salt' => $new_salt));
            $this->User->save($data, false, array('Salt'));
            $to = $this->data['User']['email'];
            $subject = "RideShare Password Reset";
            $message = "Your new RideShare password is " . $new_password;
            $headers = "";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your new password has been sent to' . $this->data['User']['email']);
        }
```

When this code executes my page displays this debugging information:

```
    Query: INSERT INTO `users` (`Password`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('81a5392c1d9687811cfeb7e66c887a4a', '2011-07-08 23:53:05', '2011-07-08 23:53:05')
    Query: INSERT INTO `users` (`Salt`) VALUES ('HjP1miaias')
```

But when I examine the database directly by going to phpMyAdmin I see that the values have not actually been updated.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO` queries insert new rows into the database. If you look at the recent entries in the database you'll probably see that it has inserted two new entries, one with the password and one with the salt. You need to set the ID so that Cake knows which entry to update before saving with `$this->User->id = $user`.

You're using `UID` as the id field's name instead of the Cake standard `id`, I don't know if that's part of the problem. (In theory it shouldn't be if the models are configured correctly to use a non-standard field name.)

Comment: I tried inserting $this->User->id = $user and $this->User->uid but the results were largely the same.  In particular the database is not being updated.  Neither are there any new rows in the table.

Comment: Actually $this->User->id = $user threw a new complaint about an undefined User.id.  $this->User->uid = gave the same results as before.

Comment: Have you configured the model to use UID instead of id?

Comment: I believe so:

<?php

class User extends AppModel {

 var $name = 'User';

 var $primaryKey = 'UID'; ...

Comment: Ah @#$%.  It turns out my code is fine.  There is something wrong with my LAMP server/CakePHP installation and that's why it's not working.